# Ignore whitespace before and after a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have **string**, for example,**" March 2018"** and I want to ignore the **whitespace** that are **before, after and also between** **March 2018** I have tried to make a regex variable like this

```
reg = new RegExp("(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December)[2]([0-9]{3})")
```

But  I don't no how to ignore whitespace 
and also if I have  **string that is duplicated the RegExp detect the first of the both**
for example 
"March 2018 Mai 2018"

Comment: `'  aaa  '.trim()` => `'aaa'`

Comment: just use [trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp).

Comment: `trim` only eliminates leading/trailing whitespace.

Comment: Use `"(January|...|December)\\s*[2]([0-9]{3})"`. Matching the first occurrence of a pattern in a test string is standard behavior. You can have repeated matches using the `/g` flag.

Comment: yes it doesn't for other space like  " In March 2018 "

Comment: @mahfoudfehim That's correct. You haven't specified this kind of pattern in your original question. Please give a comprehensive breakdown of the kind of strings you want to process.

Comment: I have try it with \\s* and it work but also \\s* before (January for the flag /g i don't have understand because i new in RegExp in JS

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code to first trim whitespace before and after the actual content and then to replace all multiple blanks by a single one:

```js
let str = "   March    2018   ";
console.log(str)
console.log(str.trim().replace(/ {2,}/g, " "));
```

Answer (score 1):

> Ignore white space before, after and within a string:

This is ECMAScript-6's functional approach (**without** using any **regex**):

```js
var str = "  a string with  white space "

var newStr = str.split(' ')
                .filter(word => word != '')
                .join(' ');

console.log(newStr);
```

It is **faster** than using **regex**. See [this](https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-es6/1)

Comment: Fairly complicated way to write `.trim().replace(/ +/g, ' ')`

Comment: Have you tested that (eg. on jsperf) ?

Comment: @collapsar **Yes** I've tested it and using ES6 is **faster**. See [this](https://jsperf.com/regex-vs-es6/1). In Chrome `regex` is 27% slower.

Comment: Your regex snippet has an additional `console.log` - not a fair comparison. In fact, your solution does not seem to be significantly faster  ( at max 10%,see [here](https://jsperf.com/ws-in-string-normalization/1) ). Not worth the cumbersome coding imho.

Comment: Btw, there is nothing ES6-specific to the solution apart from the lambda notation for the callback, which is just sytactic sugar in this setting ( equivalent to `function (word) { return (word != ''); }` which comes without discernible runtime performance penalty )

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is will work for you, happy coding :)

```js
var string = "March 2018";

console.log(string.replace(/ /g,''))
```

Comment: the question was to remove the whitespace from front , middle and last. in the solution what is posted  regex it will remove all the whitespaces from a string. I hope that a string can have white space in front, middle and last

Answer (score 0):

I hope this may help you, try the following code

```
var string="demo strings sample"; console.log(string.replace(/\s/g, ''));
```